Is it bad code or how to test/cover it with xUnit Test?
Code coverage tells me that catch statement is not covered in the code below. This is old code, and I'm not sure why it's written this way.
How do I test it? Is it even possible? Could potential exception happens if hosting computer have different culture settings? Or it's an example of bad coding, and try...catch should be removed?
public string DoSomething(string text)
{
    TimeZoneInfo tzi;

    try
    {
        tzi=TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    }
    catch
    {
        tzi=TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US/Eastern");
    }

    return text + tzi.ToString();
}


The coverage error I believe is because you do not return on all code paths.  if the code inside the catch has an exception, you do not return.  you need to rewrite that try/catch to operate properly, and/or a finally block for the tests to have coverage.  Also, those 2 attempts to get the timezoneinfo should both be in the try.  the catch should handle the potential exceptions that either of them can throw.

@Kevin that's objectively wrong. The return is outside the try/catch so all paths return. If the attempt to get a tz in the catch block fails the exception will bubble up and that's OK because that cannot possibly be handled here.

@Fildor - that is logically wrong.  If the method in the catch block throws an exception, the execution will never come back, and the return statement will not be hit.

But the error will not be raised because the analysis will recognize it as an "exit". @Kevin

That still doesn't mean all paths return...However, after digging a little deeper, I found that his specific test suite error is not because of the body of the catch, but because his test cases don't force execution of the catch.

Ah sorry, I actually mixed this up with a different question I have been commenting on. @Kevin nevermind my last one.

Well, method TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById can throw exceptions, accordingly to documentation, so removing catch clause will make functional change and can cause different behavior in many places where it is called.
So the method should stay as it is.
Accordingly to linked docs:

On Windows systems, FindSystemTimeZoneById tries to match id to the subkey names of the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones branch of the registry. On Linux and macOS, it uses time zone information available in the ICU Library. If the registry or the library does not have the information for the time zone you desire, you can create a particular time zone either by calling one of the overloads of the CreateCustomTimeZone method or by calling FromSerializedString to deserialize a TimeZoneInfo object that represents the required time zone.

So this code could throw exceptions on some machines, as this info is specific to operation system.
Moreover, the catch clause is also prone to exceptions, so this code is not handling getting time zone info correctly.
There is method TryFindSystemTimeZoneById, which is perfectly fit for such scenario:
if (!TimeZoneInfo.TryFindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time", out var tzi))
{
    if(!TimeZoneInfo.TryFindSystemTimeZoneById("US/Eastern", out tzi))
    {
        // nothing worked
        // tzi = fallback value
    }
}

return text + tzi.ToString();

Unit tests
In order to unit test it you would need to create interface for getting this time zone informations, something like this:
public interface ITimeZoneInfoProvider
{
    TimeZoneInfo FindSystemTimeZoneById(string systemTimeZoneId);
}

public class TimeZoneInfoProvider : ITimeZoneInfoProvider
{
    public TimeZoneInfo FindSystemTimeZoneById(string systemTimeZoneId)
    {
        return TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(systemTimeZoneId);
    }
}

And adjust your implementation a little:
public string DoSomething(string text)
{
    TimeZoneInfo tzi;

    try
    {
        tzi = timeZoneInfoProvider.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    }
    catch
    {
        tzi = timeZoneInfoProvider.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US/Eastern");
    }

    return text + tzi.ToString();
}

where timeZoneInfoProvider would be of type ITimeZoneInfoProvider.
Then you can mock it using Moq library and setup methods as you wish:
var mock = new Moq<ITimeZoneInfoProvider>();
// Setup mock to throw exceptions, etc.

How to force exception during debugging
Accordingly to docs, you need to adjust you OS, or easier - adjust temporarily your code - try calling FindSystemTimeZoneById for example with Guid.NewGuid().ToString() to trigger exception and see what would happen.

Like mentioned above, if they both throw exceptions? Should be try-catch-try-catch then..?

@samsergiyklok yes, there should be better handling.

yes, you should put each of them into their own try/catch and provide exception handling in each, even if it is just logging, to prevent an unhandled exception crashing your whole app.  you should also handle the case where tzi is null because both branches failed.

@Kevin I already suggested using TryFindSystemTimeZoneById to have better exception handling.

This would be perfect because it has exception handling included and returns null instead of throwing the exceptions.  Then he would just need to handle the case when tzi is null after both attempts.
